# Oracle Varchar2(byte) vs java bytes

Tags: java, oracle

I have a table having column defined varchar2(255 byte),
When I have insert record via Spring JDBC class I have an error

```
; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: de­er "DBB"."USERS"."NICK" s³tunu iin ok b³y³k (as²l: 441, maksimum: 255)
```

I have been cropping the String via following method but it does not work

```
   public static String filterStringForTxnLog(String string) {      
      try {
         String noPipe = string.replace('|', '.');
         byte noPipeBytes[]= noPipe.getBytes("UTF-8");
         if (noPipeBytes.length > 255) {
            byte [] cropBytes = new byte[255];
            for(int i=0;i<255;i++){
               cropBytes[i]=noPipeBytes[i];
            }
            return new String(cropBytes);
         }
         return noPipe;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         logger.error("Nick filter error string:" + string, e);
         return "";
      }
   }
```

When I have pass the following String size of  new String  does not fit DB column.

```
||123123123123123123123123kşlkşlkşlk12şl3l1k3şl21kşl3üğüğoşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşşş123123123123123123123123123123123123123123112321323123123123
```

Comment: What is the business problem that you're trying to solve?  It wouldn't make sense to try to truncate a UTF-8 encoded string to an arbitrary number of bytes.  If you happen to cut off in the middle of a character, that would leave you with an invalid string.  Maybe you want to truncate the string to the number of Unicode code points that can be encoded in 255 bytes (which is still problematic if you have things like combining characters).  But it seems much more likely that you want to do something like declare the column to be `varchar2(255 char)` and truncate the string at 255 characters.

Comment: yes that is the exact solution, but I do not have any priviliage to make that change thus I am trying to solve this proplem at Java level rather than that of DB.

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding issue. You have some special UTF-8 characters which are encoded in multiple bytes which is making it more than 255 bytes. Hacking it down to 255 bytes is dangerous and could lead to corruption. You need to account for the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the definition of the column to VARCHAR2(255 **CHAR**) instead.

Comment: yes that is the exact solution, but I do not have any priviliage to make that change thus I am trying to solve this proplem at Java level rather than that of DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the String creation as following, then it works properly.

```
return new String(cropBytes,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: That is still going to cause problems if 255 is in the middle of a character. It will work most of the time, but that's an edge case that will break things.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: No, but I'll give you a 5 character example =) This will gett the final character chopped in UTF-8: 1234€ The euro character takes three bytes to encode, so that 5 character string is really 7 bytes.. So if you chop it off at 5 characters, you'll get 1234 and an invalid character.

Comment: When I crop two bytes , i got 1234â as you said :)